# Stuck in an infinite loop trying to edit a scheduling algorithm

Tags: c, xv6

I am trying to change the scheduling algorithm that xv6 uses, and no matter what I do, I end up getting stuck in an infinite loop after the queue level changes once, and the output stops. I have narrowed down the issue of my code to this for loop, but I can't figure out what's wrong with it. Help would be appreciated.

```c
void
scheduler(void)
{
  struct proc *p;
  struct cpu *c = mycpu();
  c->proc = 0;


  for(;;){
    // Enable interrupts on this processor.
    sti();

   acquire(&ptable.lock);
   for (p = ptable.proc; p< &ptable.proc[NPROC]; p++) {
    if (p->state == RUNNABLE) {  
        if (p->iterationsleft == 0) {
            if (p->queuelevel == 0) {
                p->idlecount = 0;
                p->iterationsleft = 500;
            }
            else if (p->queuelevel == 1) {
                p->idlecount = 0;
                p->iterationsleft = 24;
                p->queuelevel--;
            }
            else if (p->queuelevel == 2) {
                p->idlecount = 0;
                p->iterationsleft = 16;
                p->queuelevel--;
            }
            else if (p->queuelevel == 3) {
                p->idlecount = 0;
                p->iterationsleft = 8;
                p->queuelevel--;
            }

            p->idlecount++;
        }
    }

  }
}

                                                                                                                                                                                
  // Loop over process table looking for process to run.                                                                                                                        
  for(p = ptable.proc; p < &ptable.proc[NPROC]; p++){                                                                                                                           
    if((p->state != RUNNABLE) || (p->queuelevel != 3))                                                                                                                          
      continue;                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                
    // Switch to chosen process.  It is the process's job                                                                                                                       
    // to release ptable.lock and then reacquire it                                                                                                                             
    // before jumping back to us.                                                                                                                                               
    p->idlecount = 0;                                                                                                                                                           
    p->iterationsleft--;                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                
    c->proc = p;                                                                                                                                                                
    switchuvm(p);                                                                                                                                                               
    p->state = RUNNING;                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                
    swtch(&(c->scheduler), p->context);                                                                                                                                         
    switchkvm();                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                
    // Process is done running for now.                                                                                                                                         
    // It should have changed its p->state before coming back.                                                                                                                  
    cprintf("Pos in queue: %d , Idle Count: %d , Iterations left: %d0ms.\n , Process [%s:%d] is running. \n", p->queuelevel, p->idlecount, p->iterationsleft, p->name, c->proc);
    c->proc = 0;                                                                                                                                                                
  }                                                                                                                                                                             
  release(&ptable.lock);                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                
}                                                                                                                                                                               
}
```

Comment: I don't see any way for an infinite loop.  Nothing inside the loop changes `p` so it will always advance by 1 ptable entry and eventually will get to the end - the only way to not get to the end is to change p inside the loop.  Are you sure this loop isn't inside another loop?

Comment: this is inside a for(;;) loop. forgot to mention that.

Comment: The infinite loop is because you are changing whatever the loop condition is of the outside loop.  Can you please edit the code in the question to include more code?

Comment: this is all the code before the original for loop edited in.

Comment: Ok, I am confused.  The outside loop is clearly meant to never exit and each time through it runs the inner loop (which does exit because nothing inside the loop modifies `p` and it eventually has to get to the end)  So why do you think this inner loop is causing the output to stop?

Comment: that's why I came here. I'm really stumped.

Comment: Ok, so it isn't the code.  It must be a deadlock.  The acquire call locks the ptable just before the loop.  So where does the lock get unlocked?

Comment: I didnt include the rest of the function because I didnt think it was relevant. it gets released at the bottom of the function. DO I need to release it, re-acquire it, and release it again? @JerryJeremiah

Comment: If you acquire a lock before changing data protected by it then you should release it when you are finished changing the data so that it can be acquired the next time (either by this thread or another one).  If you have multiple threads or interrupts trying to acquire this lock then try to keep the duration of the lock small so that other threads don't have to wait too long.  If you don't have other threads or interrupts trying to acquire the lock then you are wasting cycles by acquiring it here.

Comment: You acquire it in the `for(;;)` loop so when you loop around you try to acquire a lock that is already locked and everything stops. If you acquire it at the top of the function then the function only acquires and releases once so it won't self-deadlock. But if the loop takes a long time then you are holding up other threads that are trying to acquire the lock. Or you can acquire release inside the `for(;;)` loop so the function acquires and releases many times - that will use a lot of cycles but if the `for(;;)` loop takes a long time at least other threads won't be starved. It all depends.